# Marketing Cloud Landing page with form to trigger the journey by api

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

I have a landing page with a form to fire api to add user to the journey.
The landing page is a marketing cloud page.

I have created a new 'installed packages' in Apps with components.
Also We have an existing package created long time ago.
Both are using legacy for the token.

If i use the client id and client secret from old package to get the token, and do the api call, all working.
But if i use new created package to do the api call, i can get the token, but when i use that token to do the api call.
there is an error.

> Exception Error: {"message":"An error occurred when attempting to
>   evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for
>   details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException:
>   An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function
>   call. See inner exception for details.\r\n Error Code:
>   OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception
>   1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: (403) Forbidden. - from System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

Please advise whats wrong with it.

Comment: Are you using the account specific REST endpoint for your Interaction/Event API call?

Comment: Have you compared the scope of the packages?

Comment: I have figured out where the problem is. The old package supports the token passed in url, but new package doesn't support. So i have to change the function to fire the api, not include the token in url.